# Where is Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract?

Tags: c#, reference, uwp

I am calling: `FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();` to launch a win32 application in my uwp application. Then I am trying to open the connection between my uwp and win32 application, and send a message from uwp to win32. I create a `ValueSet valueSet = new ValueSet();`

But at compile time, it complains:

```
Error CS0433 The type 'ValueSet' exists in both
'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' and 'Windows,
Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'
```

I do manually add the reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd` to be able to call FullTrustProcessLauncher, and I believe I want to use the `ValueSet` inside this `Windows.winmd`.

I am confused where is the `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract`, how it is in my project? How could I remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't remove *Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract*, because is part of Windows SDK and has dependencies.
You might update to SDK version 10.0.14393.0 or greater/lower for test you app.

You have the SDK version 10.0.10586.0 where is UniversalApiContract version 2.0.

[Windows Universal Platform SDK API contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/windows-universal-sdk)

[Windows SDK and emulator archive (to download & install)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)

And you need to switch the target version of your UWP app.

Comment: This entire development system is complete and utter twaddle

Comment: Wasn't .Net supposed to remove all this "DLL Hell" - seems it just renamed it to "Assembly Lunatic Asylum" Not the dll files are hidden is hard to find places with very very very long names

Can not resolve reference: `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract`, referenced by `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract`

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy It is, except UWP isn't .NET. The Windows team tried to take over .NET with it and failed spectacularly, leaving behind a trail of C++ and XAML API guts.

Comment: And to add to the fun, the first link posted by @Sieg to [Windows Universal Platform SDK API contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/windows-universal-sdk) is broken as of now. Thanks Microsoft

Answer (score 6):

This is likely in a similar location as mine:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract#VerNum#\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd*

Wil

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out: I reference to Windows.winmd in my uwp application incorrectly. If you convert a win32 application as part of a uwp application. In the uwp application, you should refer to "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP". In the win32 application, if you would like to use uwp features, you need to refer to Windows.winmd.